# Illustrator consistently prints more saturated colors than Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, print-design

If I apply the same print profiles (Epson) to print artwork from Illustrator or Photoshop, Illustrator always prints it more saturated. Both programs use same exact working space.  Any ideas why that is?

Comment: Does the Epson printer have a postscript RIP???  Printing from Illustrator accurately needs a RIP,.. printing from Photoshop does not.

Comment: Really, why so? Can you eleborate?
I do have RIP, but know nothing about its usefulness.

Comment: In my experience, Illustrator is super inconsistent with printing. I always print my Illustrator files from InDesign.